# Trying to create a search facility but having issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having issues with my PHP code, been trying to create a search facility and am having some errors and don't know what to do. Here's my code with the area having the issues:

```
<input type="text"  required="required" name="name"> 
<input name="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
if(preg_match("^/[A-Za-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){   //to make sure its either capital or small letters
    $name=$_POST['name'];

//connection to database
$db=mysql_connect ("localhost", "<u1375454>", "<25jun94>") or die ('Cannot connect to database: ' .mysql_error());

//selection of database to use
$mydb=mysql_select_db("Cars");

 $sql="SELECT Brand i_d, Brand_name, Headquarters, Net_worth FROM Cars WHERE Brand_name LIKE '%" . $name . '%" OR Headquarters LIKE '%" . $name ."%'"; 





$result=mysql_query($sql); 
// HERES WHERE AM HAVING THE PROBLEM
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $Brand_name=$row['Brand_name']; 
  $Headquarters=$row['Headquarters']; 
  $Brand i_d=$row['Brand i_d']; 
  echo "<ul>\n"; 
  echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search.php?id=$ID\">"   .$Brand_name . " " . $Headquarters .  "</a>     </li>\n"; 
  echo "</ul>"; 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and write the whole sql query

Comment: BrandID has a space in it, should it be in brackets '[Brand i_d]'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Right now your question is unclear; what kind of errors do you have? Error messages? What do you want the code to do, and what is happening instead? Please edit that into your question. We'll need that information to help you.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to check for errors after your query. Check the "mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )" function.

Comment: Invalid variable `$Brand i_d`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "$Brand i_d" cannot be like that! change it by $Brand_i_d;